# Firebase Auth State Persistence vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not sure I'm even attempting the right thing.  Heres my issue.
I'm loading data to a screen if the user is authenticated.  Its a summary screen.  I can click a item and it will send me to a new "details" page (window.location) . I'm passing the ID in the URL and then doing a GET request to get the details to display.  When I implement my rules on the firebase DB, (".read": "auth != null"), I get a "401 Unauthorized" error in the console.
So somehow I need to either pass the user to the details.js or set Persistence somehow.  Anyone have any suggestions?

THIS IS THE CODE FROM THE MAIN.JS

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    console.log(user);
    if (user) {
        database.on('value', function(data) {
            myData = data.val()
            keys = Object.keys(myData)
            buildProperties();
        })
        // tempBuild()
    } else {
        $('.eachProperty').empty()
        $('.eachProperty').append($(`<h1>You must be signed in to view properties</h1>`))
    }
})


$('body').on('click', '.singleProp', function() {

    id = $(this).attr('id')
     window.location = "/details.html?id=" + id

})
```

THIS IS THE CODE FROM THE DETAILS.JS

```
 var myLocation = location.search.slice(4)
    $.get(`https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/property/${myLocation}/.json`).then(myProperty)

    function myProperty(prop) {
        $('.propAddress').text(prop.address)
        $('.zip').text(prop.zip)

        if(prop.pictures){
            for (var i = 0; i < prop.pictures.length; i++) {
                var myImg = prop.pictures[i]
                $('.imgContainer').append($(`<div class="eachPicDiv"><img src="${myImg}" alt="0" class="detailPic">
                <ion-icon class="rBtn" name="arrow-redo-outline"></ion-icon>
                </div`))
            }
        } else {
            $('.imgContainer').append($(`<h1>THERE WERE NO PICTURES</h1>`))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery to fetch your data from Firebase Database,
[$.get is a jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method, and for that to succeed you need to have some sort of auth token.
Firebase already provides best in class access, [read more about access here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).
[Learn by example here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0).